# Compile python into binary - pypy performance

Tags: python, compilation, pyinstaller, pypy

I am looking to compile python source code into a binary. I generally use pypy for performance reasons (my application runs significantly faster using pypy). I found this answer from 2012 stating compiling pypy into binary isn't possible using any of the existing tools (e.g. pyinstaller). [Compile PyPy to Exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470800/compile-pypy-to-exe). I wasn't quite able to follow what the top response was explaining as a solution.

I am wondering:

1. Is there now a reasonably easy way to compile python code to binary using pypy as the interpreter?
2. I don't actually need to use pypy, I just use it for the performance gains. Is there a reasonable way to avoid using pypy but still get similar performance gains? This would still need to support compiling to binary.

As an additional note, I use the 2.7 syntax.

Answer (score 6):

you can take a look to nuitka ( http://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html)

```
 nuitka --standalone --recurse-on --python-version=2.7 main.py
```

Comment: perhaps --standalone instead of --standalon ?